# Flutter app elements on the screen get larger on iPad

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

My app looks chunkier on the iPad simulator than on the iPhone simulator:

[image]

It seems to be scaling everything up. It looks better when the minimise button is clicked on the iPad simulator:

[image]

The default behaviour with flutter is meant to be that it resizes, not scales, which keeps the objects the same size and they just take up a smaller portion of the screen, but here we can see it is actually making the objects larger so that they take up the same portion of the screen on iPad. Why? It looks like the app doesn't support iPad, but I have set the targeted device families to iPhone, and iPad:

[image]

EDIT: Also the app should take up the entire width of the iPad, but it has been cut off before the edge, showing black strips.

Answer (score 0):

Had to give iPad the tick here:

[image]

Note I had the same issue on web, where the buttons became thicker. I resolved that with this:

In my themes, I changed `visualDensity: VisualDensity.standard` to `visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity`. That assigns the correct visual density for every platform. Now my buttons don't become taller on any platform.